# AWS Launch Configuration error: The requested configuration is currently not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created a **Launch Configuration** with which I am creating a **Auto Scaling Group**.

When I create the **Auto Scaling Group** from the **Launch Configuration**, I get the below error:

```
Description:DescriptionLaunching a new EC2 instance. Status Reason: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations. Launching EC2 instance failed.

Cause:CauseAt 2017-08-15T10:54:52Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1.
```

I looked around and only found [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/ts-as-instancelaunchfailure.html#ts-as-instancelaunchfailure-3) link. However, it doesn't tell me what exactly isn't supported, so doesn't help much.

My **Launch Configuration** looks like this:

[image]

My **Auto Scaling Group** looks like this:

[image]

And:

[image]

Sorry I had to block some items out as it has the client's data.

Any input will help. As there is no information anywhere in the logs, I don't know where to go from here.

PS: I have tried changing the **Instance Type** but had no luck. Thought that might be the cause but apparently not.

Comment: Do the security groups match the right VPC and subnets? Is the instance type available, and is it available for that ami? Try spinning up a box manually with the parameters in your launch config, you might get "better" errors.

Comment: Thanks Raf. I will check this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: The issue was with the VPC, as per my answer below. Thanks for your help Raf anyway mate. I like the approach of testing out stuff manually to get a better idea of what exactly is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out. My VPC was set to Dedicated Tenancy, which doesn't support all types of instances. The Dedicated setting was done in error actually. I deleted the VPC (you can't seem to change its Tenancy setting) and then created a new one, followed the steps for the Launch Configuration and the ASG created the instances without a problem.

Comment: Thanks!  The same hard to troubleshoot issue was affecting one of my CloudFormation templates. `"InstanceTenancy" : "default"` fixed it

Answer (score 17):

I got this same error and after knocking my head against the wall for a while (and testing a lot) in my case the culprit was that I had the ebs-optimized flag enabled on my launch template

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I was using a t2.medium, which is not supported https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html

Answer (score 15):

There will be different answers to this question, but as Raf said a good place to start is your VPC, subnet, instance types, and AMI.

My issue was that AWS deprecated my instance type (m3) in my specific region. Easiest way to check is to go to the EC2 tab in AWS console and try to launch your specific setup manually.

Comment: This is AWS side problem, it would be nice if they provide us with much useful error, rather than "something wrong happen" which basically says nothing...Sorry for the rant

Comment: This is my upvote answer, just create the whole thing manually first and see where is your problem. I had the same problem when I wanted to switch from eu-west-1 to eu-north-1. And basically t2.micro is not supported in eu-north-1. So the terraform needed some modifications like changing the instance type from t2.micro to t3.micro. Luckily, I saw that only t3.micro was available when I tried to create the EC2 instance manually.

Answer (score 7):

Manual launching of instance via EC2 was the only thing that helped: I noticed that InstanceType that was eligible for Free Tier was t3.micro, while one in my lab's template was t2.micro. Apparently using t2.micro for my ImageId was resulting in infamous 'requested configuration is currently not supported' error, at attempting to create instances defined by the template.

Once I was able to manually launch specified ImageId and InstanceType, I was able to replicate it with CloudFormation template and finally create stack successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I too, was facing this issue because my VPC was set to **dedicated** tenancy. The error message today is very helpful, in saying that

> The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.

(without providing any link to this documentation). I wanted to link it here for anyone who is looking for it-

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-instance.html) page mentions that

> Some instance types cannot be launched into a VPC with the instance tenancy set to dedicated.

Changing my instance type to one of those mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/dedicated-instances/) fixed this issue for me. I did not have to create a new VPC with **default** tenancy, although that is also a good solution if you have the permission to do that.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was because of using instance type unavailable for specific AWS region.

Answer (score 3):

My case was the combination of:

```
instance_type = "t2.micro"
ebs_optimized = true
```

Switching to `t3.micro` fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a default tenancy and had no desire to change it. In my case the solution was to change the instance type. Simple as that. Simply changed from "Amazon Linux 2" to "Ubuntu 20.04".

Answer (score 0):

Yes for some reason if you chose `t2.micro` while creating the instance and then you want to move to the latest generation like `M7a` etc..

To fix,

1. Change the instance type to `t3 or t3a family`
2. Start & Stop the instance
3. Change the instance type to your choice of `family.size`